# How to convert img tag into css selector

Tags: html, css, selenium-webdriver

I want this tag to be convert into  WebElemet but using CSS Selector
I have tried with Xpath as given in below snippet:

```
 panelSectionTitle.find( By.xpath( "//*[local-name() = 'img'][@class=
    'aw-layout-right' and @style='']" ) )
 <img style="" class="aw-layout-right" height="22" width="22">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below css selector

```
img.aw-layout-right[width='22'][height='22']
```

**EDIT**:

If you want to locate the img with only class and style Attributes then

```
 img.aw-layout-right[style='']
```

**UPDATE**:

Solution for

> By.xpath( "//*[local-name() = 'svg'][@width='22' and @height = '22']"

```
svg[width='22'][height='22']
```

Hope this helps you.Kindly get back if you have any queries

Comment: no its not working..getting unable to locate exception

Comment: post ur full html code i tried for the above code  <img style="" class="aw-layout-right" height="22" width="22"> it is working

Comment: <img style="" class="aw-layout-right" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABYAAAAWCAYAAADEtGw7AAAA6ElEQVR42rVVbQ3EIAxFwkmYhEk4CUg4CZOACwJ/sIKUSZiDO0raXMfHWBa6pMnSvj7aVz6UGnze+9U5p5MZNA0+9eQLIbyQZE/27RjEDGBvkVpr3wPCaoFhBwnwKZIi+NJiC1t4QVzkWPBdaUnAI9k26g4wiCXytaUptX+UAJQnDw/+GwUR+X7SHJOo2q1RGY+bTuV1nFUbOy1fEiOGNN8rbXsDuEPMB5+lxM2fHTR9rika3wGRx0hzyGUYfaqmU+HIDMv7+ySJZaQQG57YdhM9IGJHmiXPvYREr82itbkXvejTNOsx/QENjcWxm65saAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" height="22" width="22">

Comment: The css selector provided by me in the above post is working fine for the html code.You can verify it by just creating an html page(like the one below) and try to access the image tag using the above css selector shortcut in chrome : $$('img.aw-layout-right[style='']') or using selenium script both works.see if the element is present inside an iframe or if it is disabled using any javascript if not provide a link to the website.

Comment: <html>
<body>
<img style="" class="aw-layout-right" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABYAAAAWCAYAAADEtGw7AAAA6ElEQ‌​VR42rVVbQ3EIAxFwkmYhEk4CUg4CZOACwJ/sIKUSZiDO0raXMfHWBa6pMnSvj7aVz6UGnze+9U5p5MZNA‌​0+9eQLIbyQZE/27RjEDGBvkVpr3wPCaoFhBwnwKZIi+NJiC1t4QVzkWPBdaUnAI9k26g4wiCXytaUptX+‌​UAJQnDw/+GwUR+X7SHJOo2q1RGY+bTuV1nFUbOy1fEiOGNN8rbXsDuEPMB5+lxM2fHTR9rika3wGRx0hz‌​yGUYfaqmU+HIDMv7+ySJZaQQG57YdhM9IGJHmiXPvYREr82itbkXvejTNOsx/QENjcWxm65saAAAAABJR‌​U5ErkJggg==" height="22" width="22">
</body>
</html>

Comment: yes its working. then what is the solution for this element?               By.xpath( "//*[local-name() = 'svg'][@width='22' and @height = '22']"

Comment: Have added css selector for the above xpath its working fine pls refer the above post.Kindly chk and get back

Comment: @AvinashJadhav If the above solution worked for you kindly do accept & upvote the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can select an image tag in selenium like this :

HTML :

```
<img style="" class="aw-layout-right" height="22" width="22">
```

java :

```
 driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("img.aw-layout-right"))
```